# Unable to attach remote debugger to Eclipse OSGi application

Tags: eclipse, osgi, remote-debugging, equinox, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to remote debug an Eclipse (OSGi) Application using the Intellij IDEA's *Remote* run configuration. Unfortunately, every time I run the application in Eclipse, the app never waits for a remote connection and I'm unable to attach a remote debugger to it.

I configured the Eclipse run configuration by adding the following argument to *Run > Run Configurations... > Eclipse Application > Arguments*: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y`.

When I run the configuration in Eclipse the application starts immediately instead of the JVM waiting for the remote connection, even though I defined the `suspend=y` parameter. If I try to run the Intellij remote configuration, it gives the following message: `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:6000): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"`.

I also tried to make the Eclipse app attach (instead of listening) to the Intellij IDEAs remote debugger, but it also didn't work (the app didn't try to connect to the remote debugger).

The following images show the run configurations:

[image: Eclipse Application's run configuration]
[image: Intellij IDEA's remote configuration]

Other information:

- **OS:** Windows 10
- **Eclipse:** Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
- **Intellij IDEA:** 2019.3

Comment: `-agentlib` is not a program but a VM argument (you entered it in the wrong field). IMHO a hammer is not the right tool for a screw.

Comment: You're correct. I tried setting up the app to run in Intellij IDEA, but was defeated. Since I'm not familiar with Eclipse, I decided to use Intellij to develop the app and Eclipse just to launch it.

Comment: The problem is not the insufficient support that slows you down, but that you are blind to issues that occur at runtime. This is even worse than using a text editor for plain Java applications where there is no code completion but compile errors are shown on compiling. When using declarative programming, tool-support is needed to see issues before running the application and not have to waste time on debugging (where these issues are very hard to analyze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119522/unable-to-attach-remote-debugger-to-eclipse-osgi-application#comment104469425_59119522), the correct place for that argument is in the "*VM arguments*" (not the "*Program arguments*"). After that change, the application now correctly waits for the debugger to attach.

[image: Eclipse Application's fixed run configuration]